# setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:

Tags: ios, voip

I'm developing a simple VoIP app but am having trouble understanding how it works. Here is my AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Set-up scheduled background check-in.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
        //do your task
        NSLog(@"startingKeepAliveTimeout");

    }];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Set-up scheduled background check-in.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
        //do your task
        NSLog(@"startingKeepAliveTimeout");

    }];

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] clearKeepAliveTimeout];
    NSLog(@"stoppingKeepAliveTimeout");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

@end
```

The problem I am seeing, both in the simulator and on a connected device is that when I launch the app I see the NSLog(@"stoppingKeepAliveTimeout"); being executed from the applicationWillEnterForeground: method but I never see NSLog(@"startingKeepAliveTimeout"); either when the app is initially launched or when it is executed from applicationDidEnterBackground:

How can I tell if the keepalive is actually working or even being called?

Comment: Is your project marked as being a VoIP app? Do you have any VoIP sockets? Btw, simulator won't work for you AFAIK…

Comment: Yes, its marked as voip. My understanding is that if the keepalive is functioning properly it is not necessary to separately create a socket. Even if voip doesn't work in the simulator the method should stil get called and the console display correctly.